# Integrating a .Net service with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: .net, integration, exchange-server

Are there any API's for integrating a server side application with Microsoft Exchange?

I have a server application that needs to read contact/prospect information entered into exchange via Outlook. What's the best approach? Outlook automation, or is there some sort of API I can use?

My environment is .Net/C#.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You havn't specified which version of Exchange Server you want to integrate with.

In Exchange 2010 you can use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877012.aspx).

In earlier versions of Exchange you can use various technologies like [Exchange WebDAV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms876446(v=EXCHG.65).aspx) and [Collaboration Data Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms988614(v=EXCHG.65).aspx).